# Clipped Image calls TapAction outside frame

Tags: swift, image, swiftui

I have a issue concerning the tapAction on a image. The TapAction closure gets called on the clipped area which shouldn't happen. What should I do?

```
Image(uiImage: image)
    .resizable()
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
    .frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
    .presentation(tapped ? Modal(Image(uiImage: image)) : nil)
    .clipped()
    .cornerRadius(10)
    .border(Color.black, width: 2, cornerRadius: 10)
    .tapAction {
        self.tapped.toggle()
    }
```

That's the result:

[image]

Comment: just a guess - aside from possibly being a bug, have you tried changing to order of your modifiers? I can have an affect. Check out this about the tappable area of a `Button` (and yes, it's not the same as an `Image`): https://alejandromp.com/blog/2019/06/09/playing-with-swiftui-buttons/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Update**

I updated my answer. This is the proper way of doing it. There is a modifier called `contentShape()` that you can use to define the hit test area:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var tapped = false

    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
            .frame(height: 200, alignment: .center)
            .presentation(tapped ? Modal(Image(systemName: "photo")) : nil)
            .clipped()
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .border(Color.black, width: 2, cornerRadius: 10)
            .contentShape(TapShape())
            .tapAction {
                self.tapped.toggle()
            }
    }

    struct TapShape : Shape {
        func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
            return Path(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: rect.width, height: 200))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG Thank you  I've tried so much but this is perfect

Comment: What i've tried before is to have a RoundedRectangle which its background is the image but nothing has changed

Comment: Hi @jsbeginnerNodeJS, I updated my answer. It turns out there is a proper way of doing it, without resorting to .opacity(0.00001).

Comment: Oh, I've been looking for a solution for this for quite a bit now; thank you! It really feels weird to have to always call `contentShape` whenever we use `clipped`/`masked`, just so touches don't register outside. There's also the "reverse" — the invisible parts of the image might "cover" an adjacent button which won't work anymore (my actual issue)... I already miss `clipsToBounds`.

Comment: Thank you! This saved me from a bunch of frustration.

Comment: This seems to work, replacing a Button with the `.onTapGesture` fixed the same issue I was having. (Note that `.onTapGesture` is now the current syntax, rather than `.tapAction`.

Comment: BTW: ensures that outside the contentShape all gestures on  views in the parent view are available and not hidden by this view.