# Why does the frame modifier still affect other views when attached to nil image?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

```
self.imagesViewModel.allImages[post.imageContentURL]?
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(width: 343, height: 171, alignment: .center)
    .clipShape(Rectangle())
    .shadow(radius: 1)
```

What this code is supposed to do is nothing when the image value returned is `nil`. But for whatever reason, the `.frame` modifier still affects other elements inside of a scroll view. It ends up obstructing navigation links physically, but not visually.

I've confirmed that when `.frame` is removed, everything works as I intend it to. But I need to set limits on the images, so I can't do without something of the sort.

I've tried placing the code inside of an if statement to check for `nil` and only display upon an image being returned, but that didn't work. Other variations of this code also don't work.

```
if self.imagesViewModel.allImages[post.imageContentURL] != nil {
    self.imagesViewModel.allImages[post.imageContentURL]?
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .frame(width: 343, height: 171)
        .clipShape(Rectangle())
        .shadow(radius: 1)
}
```

I've also tried setting min values to zero with no luck.

I'm wondering if it has anything to do with me being on Xcode 12 beta 5, or with using the new SwiftUI app lifecycle. When I run the code on my iPhone (iOS 14), I get the same physical obstructions, but addition visual spacing added between scrollview elements.

Here is a simplified version of my code that replicates my problem:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Post: Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var text: String
    var imageContentURL: String?
}

class PostsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var posts: [Post] = []
}

class ImagesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var allImages: [String?: Image] = [:]
}

/// The View of the content displayed in Home
struct PostLayout: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var imagesViewModel: ImagesViewModel
    var post: Post
    
    init(post: Post) {
        self.post = post
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // This is the navigation link that gets obstructed
            NavigationLink(destination: SomeOtherView()) {
                Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 48, height: 48)
                    .clipShape(Circle())
            }
            
            Text(self.post.text)
            
            // MARK: This is the problem code, border added for clarity
            self.imagesViewModel.allImages[self.post.imageContentURL]?
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 343, height: 171)
                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                .shadow(radius: 1)
                .border(Color.black, width: 1)
        }
        .border(Color.black, width: 1)
    }
}

/// View that is navigated to from Home
struct SomeOtherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("SomeOtherView")
    }
}

/// Main displayed view
struct Home: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var postsViewModel: PostsViewModel
    @EnvironmentObject var imagesViewModel: ImagesViewModel

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(self.postsViewModel.posts) { post in
                    PostLayout(post: post)
                }
            }
            .onAppear() {
                // All displayed content created here
                var post1 = Post(id: 0, text: "Content")
                let post2 = Post(id: 1, text: "Content")
                var post3 = Post(id: 2, text: "Content")
                let post4 = Post(id: 3, text: "Content")
                let imageURL = "someImageURL"
                
                self.imagesViewModel.allImages[imageURL] = Image(systemName: "circle")
                
                // Only two posts are supposed to have an imageURL
                post1.imageContentURL = imageURL
                post3.imageContentURL = imageURL
                self.postsViewModel.posts.append(contentsOf: [post1, post2, post3, post4])
            }
            .navigationTitle("Home")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Home()
            .environmentObject(PostsViewModel())
            .environmentObject(ImagesViewModel())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem has nothing to do with `nil` or the frame modifier.

The image was actually extending invisibly beyond the boundaries of `.clipShape(Rectangle())` and was blocking the NavigationLink. The solution is to use a combination of `.contentShape()` and `.clipped`.

```
self.imagesViewModel.allImages[self.post.imageContentURL]?
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(width: 343, height: 171)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .clipped()
    .shadow(radius: 1)
```

I discovered this answer from the post here:
[Clipped Image calls TapAction outside frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57013933/clipped-image-calls-tapaction-outside-frame)

Answer (score 1):

As you've already noticed the `.frame` modifier is not *Image-specific*. It will work even if the Image is `nil`.

What you can do is to check if the `Image` can be loaded. You can do this by using `UIImage(named:)` (which returns an Optional):

```
@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    if UIImage(named: "imageName") != nil {
        Image("imageName")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 343, height: 171, alignment: .center)
            ...
    }
}
```

or, alternatively:

```
@ViewBuilder
var body: some View {
    if imagesViewModel.allImages[post.imageContentURL] != nil {
        imagesViewModel.allImages[post.imageContentURL]!
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .frame(width: 343, height: 171, alignment: .center)
            ...
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

There's no need for an optional `String?` in dict. Simply replace it with:

```
@Published var allImages: [String: Image] = [:]
```

Then use `if` statement to check if the image is not nil (in Xcode 12 you may use `if-let` as well):

```
if self.post.imageContentURL != nil {
    self.imagesViewModel.allImages[self.post.imageContentURL!]?
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .frame(width: 343, height: 171)
        .clipShape(Rectangle())
        .shadow(radius: 1)
        .border(Color.black, width: 1)
}
```

Comment: I've given both a try, and nothing changes. I've also tried all the other solutions here with no luck.

Comment: @Mark-4421 Please post more code of your view - but try to make it a *minimal* example.

Comment: I've updated my post with the most minimal example I could make. It should perfectly display what my problem is if you run it in Xcode (12 beta).

Comment: @Mark-4421 Thanks, this is a really good example. I updated my answer - let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I've made the suggested changes, but the outcome remains the same. Did it work on your end?

Comment: @Mark-4421 Yes, but it may be that I misunderstood your question. What did you exactly mean by *It ends up obstructing navigation links physically, but not visually*?

Comment: In the example code I wrote, there's a NavigationLink "circle.filled". When an image is being displayed in a PostLayout, the NavigationLink can't be clicked on. When an image is not displayed, the NavigationLink can be clicked on. Nothing visually blocks the link, but something invisible to do with .frame, does.

Comment: I've solved the issue and posted the answer below. Apparently ```.clipShape()``` only visually clips images.

Comment: @Mark-4421 I was just updating my post with the exact same answer :)

Comment: I still want to say thanks, because writing the simplified version helped me understand the issue better!

Comment: @Mark-4421 You're welcome. The best way to say thanks in SO is by upvoting :)

Comment: @Mark-4421 Also you can accept your own answer as it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the actual image has issues but the SwiftUI view of type `Image` exists. `Image` is more like `UIImageView` than `UIImage`, even though it's really not helpful to think of it as being either one. What you probably want is:

```
    var body: some View {
        if imageView == nil {
            EmptyView()
        } else {
            imageView?
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(width: 343, height: 171, alignment: .center)
                .clipShape(Rectangle())
                .shadow(radius: 1)
                .border(Color.black)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use if-let (Xcode 12+):

```
if let image = self.imagesViewModel.allImages[post.imageContentURL]? {
    image
    .resizable()
    .scaledToFill()
    .frame(width: 343, height: 171, alignment: .center)
    .clipShape(Rectangle())
    .shadow(radius: 1)
}
```